# How to split a Bitcoin Core wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, wallet.dat

I have an 'omnibus' wallet.dat which holds balances for multiple parties which I would like to disentangle and split. The UTXOs are not blended, each UTXO is owned by a given party in whole and there  has been no key reuse throughout the wallet's life. It is not an HD wallet.

Q) What is the best way to 'fork' this wallet into multiple new wallet files, one per party, such that I can retire/deprecate (obviously not delete) the old wallet, while still propagating the same UTXO states and transaction histories into the new wallets?

This is a question about delicate wallet manipulation without any on-chain activity.

I have tried `dumpwallet` to obtain the list of keys+addresses, separated the relevant ones manually and then used `importwallet` on each resultant file into a new wallet.dat for each. This sometimes loses address labels, and seems to adjust the transaction timestamps versus the original file. There is apparently some metadata lost in the transfer, *is there a better method for what I'm trying to achieve?*